# angular is not defined, why?

Tags: angularjs

The following angular piece doesn't work, it seems that in the immediately invoked function the code breaks where I create my module because angular syntax is not recognised.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyModule">
 <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.17/angular2.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrller">          
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    {{ cousin }}
  </body>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("MyModule", []);
    var MyCtrller = function($scope)          ///typo here in "MyCtrller"
    {
          $scope.cousin = "Karen";
    }
    app.controller("MyCtrller", ["$scope", MyCtrller]);
}());
</script>
```

I expect the result to be Karen.

Instead, I see {{ cousin }}

The error I get in console is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

on the line where I create my module:

`var app = angular.module("MyModule", []);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are including the v2.0 version of angular (a.k.a. Angular), instead of 1.x version (a.k.a. AngularJS) while using the latter syntax. :)
Simply change your script to use the correct version and you should be good to go.

https://angularjs.org/

Comment: Sorry don't understand. You said I should use 1.x so I added: `<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.6.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.7/angular.js"></script>` but it still doesn't work. What if I want to use version 2 (Angular JS), how should the rest of my code change? Presumably I should use 2 if it's more advanced right?

Comment: No. It's a totally different beast.

Comment: There was a typo in MyCtroller definition

Comment: Yes working now thank you very much. But should I rather modify the angular syntax to fit the version 2 (Angular) since this should be more advanced than 1? I wasn't even aware there are big differences.

Comment: Theres no good answer for that question. As mentioned, angular 1 and 2 have quite different syntax'es meaning that while concept stay similar, its "learning from the start". If you're willing v.2 (actually v.5 now) is probably better choice when it comes to future support, but its "entry level" is much higher than v.1 (i.e. you need to get more code to start an app in it)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the AngularJs script instead of Angular Script in your script like this

```
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.7/angular.js"></script>
```